# On hover bar is overlapped by label chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to generate a bar graph but after generating when i hover on bar first graph the hover works and tooltip is also coming correctly but when i hover on second or third bar the bar color becomes black

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="barChart" style="margin-top:10px"></canvas>

var ctxBarChart = document.getElementById('barChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxBarChart, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'bar',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ['bar 1', 'bar 2', 'bar 3'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'bar graph label',
                backgroundColor: ['#ff7f27', 'DodgerBlue', 'Green'],
                borderColor: ['#ff7f27', 'DodgerBlue', 'Green'],
                data: [24.6154, 28.4, 28.4]
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        return tooltipItem.yLabel.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,') + '%';
                    }
                }
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        // max: 100,
                        min: 0,
                        // stepSize:20
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

but the result i'm getting is like this please see following images for bar 1 and bar 2
[image: Bar 1 image]
[image: Bar 2 image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by case-sensitivity of colour names.

Change your colours to all lowercase like so:

```
backgroundColor: ['#ff7f27', 'dodgerblue', 'green'],
borderColor: ['#ff7f27', 'dodgerblue', 'green'],
```

The [CSS3 specification explicitly states](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#html4) the names are case-insensitive so this looks like a bug in Chart.js